# How to automatically adjust the height of iframe to fit the contents using javascript or css

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, iframe

I have an iframe embedding a pdf file but I want to ensure that the iframe extends its height automatically according to the contents in it so that the iframe scrolling bars are not shown, but every time I try the results comes unexpected here are my sample code

Here is what I tried

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Iframe</title>
<style>
    iframe{
        width: 100%;
        border: 2px solid #ccc;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="demo.pdf" id="myIframe"></iframe>
    
    <script>
    var iframe = document.getElementById("myIframe");
 
    iframe.onload = function(){
        iframe.style.height = iframe.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try `iframe:{height:max-content}` or use `<embed>` html tag

Answer (score 0):

- Remove the `height` in script
- add `fit-content` in css

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Iframe</title>
<style>
    iframe{
        height: fit-content;
        width: 100%;
        border: 2px solid #ccc;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="demo.pdf" id="myIframe"></iframe>
    
    <script>
    var iframe = document.getElementById("myIframe");
 
    iframe.onload = function(){
    iframe.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please restrain from posting code only answers without any further explanation (or only diffing). A comment to the best fitting - in your opinion - existing Q&A material on site might be another alternative approach to consider. It's often quicker than quickly copy&pasting in some code and provides more context and helps building a great Q&A.

Comment: As you can see, I provided text that is not code.

Comment: Yes, you highlighted the difference, but IMHO this is not explaining much. It does add some text, that's true thought. At the end of the day, you have to judge your own answer, not me. That was only my comment (and started early without the edit). You can also reference existing Q&A by placing a link in your answer and then the question will highlight that on-site-reference prominently as well in the side-bar.